# Hibernate : class not found exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I've create all my class in this package "com.faycal.model.NameClass"

and in my ".hbm.xml" file i've declare the class as this :

```
<class name="com.faycal.model.RecetteIngredient" 
        table="recette_ingredients" catalog="myapp">
...
</class>
```

in HibernateSessionFactory i've add the mappingRessource like this :

```
<property name="mappingLocations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:com/faycal/hibernate/*.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

the orthers class are loaded ok, and for RecetteIngredient i've this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.faycal.model.RecetteIngredient
```

full stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/beans/HibernateSessionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.buildType(Component.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:98)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: component class not found: com.faycal.model.RecetteIngredient
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildGetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.<init>(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.<init>(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:38)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.faycal.model.RecetteIngredient
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:101)
    ... 47 more

janv. 26, 2015 10:06:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/beans/HibernateSessionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.buildType(Component.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:98)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: component class not found: com.faycal.model.RecetteIngredient
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildGetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.<init>(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.<init>(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:38)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.faycal.model.RecetteIngredient
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:101)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: The classname is propably not what you expect it to be. Check the casing, single t or double t etc.

Comment: It's All with double t @M.Deinum

Comment: The classpath isn't lying so the class either isn't there or you have the name wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the class is compiled properly?

Comment: Yes, it's compiled correctly.

I've found the problem, i've change ALL the capital letter of class "RecetteIngredient" to tiny letter "Recetteingredient", with this, it works... i dont know why

Comment: Always start with working example.